# QBO3 Queue Paused and Won't Restart

Tags: message-queue, qbo3

In a QBO3 system, the Design > Configuration > Queuing page includes several queues in a Paused status.  When I attempt to start the queue via the GUI, it very quickly reverts to a Paused status. When I recycle the Queue Service, and then attempt to start the queue via the GUI, it again quickly reverts to a Paused status.  Here are the properties of one of the paused queues:

[image: Queues Paused]

Answer (score 0):

When a queue is paused, you can determine the root cause of the pause from the Debug Queue Log. From Design > Configuration > Queuing, click on the search icon under the queue's Debug Log column.

There are two common reasons for a queue being automatically paused.

**Pause after X consecutive errors**

A queue may be configured to paused after a certain number of consecutive errors. This is typically done to ensure that QBO3 does not 'spin it wheels' when there is something configured improperly.

To control the characteristics of such pauses, edit the queue, and set the following fields under the Queue Retry section:

- Pause after: enter the number of consecutive failures that should cause a pause. Leave blank to avoid pausing
- Restart: enter the number of restarts that will be allowed. This is useful for queues that interface with third party systems that may be down for a period of time.

  - After X {minutes | hours | days}: determines how long the queue must wait before restarting.

**Queue Configuration Error**

A queue may be configured with incorrect information, such as:

- a missing IQueue plugin (e.g. the installation is missing a IQueue plugin like ServiceBroker or SNS)
- a missing Schedule (e.g. the Queue.Schedule is defined, but there is no matching entry in the Schedule table.  Run Design > Packages > Queue Initialization for standard schedules.)

For example, the Debug log for a queue with an invalid schedule would display an error along these lines:

> FileExport, queue paused on 6/2/2016 9:52:31 AM. Pause count 1. Resume
>   count . No resume date. Schedule Access Error Either this record does
>   not exist, or you do not have access to it. Object 'Schedule',
>   ObjectID '0'